# Isotope equal height for all items

Tags: css, height, jquery-isotope

I am using jQuery isotope on my web page.
I know how isotope works but I need the height of all elements to be equal
or double the height so all lines up straight at the bottom part of the elements.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
http://prntscr.com/be5qcm

and this is my live page:
http://www.clients.tipoos.com/contini-project/single-artists.html

here is my code:

```
$(".single-artist-wrapper").isotope({
    itemSelector: ".artist-box",
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 1
    }
    });

    var $grid2 = $(".single-artist-wrapper").isotope({});

    $(".single-artist-nav").on("click", "a", function() {
        var a = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        $grid2.isotope({
            filter: a
        });
    });

    var $optionSets = $(".single-artist-nav"), $optionLinks = $optionSets.find("a");

    $optionLinks.click(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        if (a.hasClass("selected")) return false;
        var b = a.parents(".single-artist-nav");
        b.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        a.addClass("selected");
    });
```

Here is a fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/5m3Lxvrs/8/

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle? - it will make it easier to adjust corresponding CSS and isotope properties. :)

Comment: Updated the code above + fiddle.  Thanks @Frits